# Could Puppet-reports be removed once these have been processed by Puppet-dashboard or PuppetDB?

Tags: disk-space-utilization, puppet-dashboard, puppetdb, puppet

Puppet-reports are using a lot of diskspace in:

```
/var/lib/puppet/reports
/var/lib/mysql
```

The assumption is that it stores all reports in the MySQL database, because both paths are about the same size. The *resource_statuses* table consist of rows that each represent a line in a reports file.

- Can one safely remove the reports in /var/lib/puppet/reports after
  Puppet-dashboard or PuppetDB has processed them?
- What is the best practice for handling reports?
- Is
  there a way to make Puppet-dashboard automatically delete the *yaml*
  report files after processing them?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes you can delete them and I recommend it as well. The docs for Puppet dashboard aren't very opinionated on the ongoing maintenance of the dashboard, but it does need maintenance. I recommend a cron that delete reports in the database after a few days, a second one to remove any orphaned records, and a third to delete processed reports. Mine looks like this:

```
cd /path/to dashboard ; RAILS_ENV=production rake reports:prune upto=3 unit=day
cd /path/to dashboard ; RAILS_ENV=production rake reports:prune:orphaned
find /var/lib/puppet/var/reports/ -mmin +300 -type f -print0 | xargs -0 -r rm > /dev/null 2>&1
```

You can tweak the times to what works best for your system. I don't believe the delayed_job contains any functionality to delete processed reports, but you might be able to add it to code.

Comment: I hope you're using puppet to set up the cron ^^;