# Disk usage of Puppet reports

Tags: logging, puppet, logrotate, puppetmaster

We are running puppet-dashboard on the puppetmaster which processes all the reports and puts them in a MySQL table. Every month about 5GB of reports are generated however in /var/lib/puppet/reports.

What is the best way to control disk usage for Puppet reports?

- Daily prune all reports older than 30 days with a cronjob.
- Using logrotate on older report files (.yaml), if possible.

I am sure there are many people that have Puppet logging many gigabytes every month. It seems too expensive to keep storing this data.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.puppetlabs.com/dashboard/manual/1.2/maintaining.html

See "Cleaning Old Reports"

Also:
[Could Puppet-reports be removed once these have been processed by Puppet-dashboard or PuppetDB?](https://serverfault.com/questions/521827/can-i-remove-puppet-reports-after-puppet-dashboard-processed-them)

Comment: -1 -  link doesn't work anymore. Never post links as only content of answer. Please add some quotes from the links in addition to the links.